# React and web API do they have to be in same project?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create an app with a react frontend and make calls to a web api in Visual Studio 2019.  I had originally created the API in it's own project and the react front end in it's own project but when I try to test it locally I get an error that it can't find the web address of the API. The examples I see on here as well as on other sites have the controllers and logic in the same project. My question is which is the correct way to design this?

Comment: There isn't a "correct" way to do it, it's up to you and your requirements.  I have projects where UI and API are in the same project and others where they are in separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't have to be in the same project. if the API project is running on you rlocal machine then you can send request to `http://localhost:PORT/api-path`

Comment: That is what I'm doing but I get a Cors error stating "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/DCandidate/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: You have to add proxy in your package.json file

Comment: you have to enable CORS on the web api project and allow localhost:3000 to handle requests from a separate origin localhost:3001 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api